# Why is rowspan not working if i switch the order of the cells?

Tags: html, layout, html-table

I have a really simple example that is driving me crazy. Can someone explain why is this working

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td rowspan="2">$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

While this isn't?

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td rowspan="2">$100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest way to understand what's happening here is to add a third row.

Firstly, we can have a table where the $100 spans January and February, but not March:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td rowspan="2">$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>March</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then, we can have one that spans February and March, but not January:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td rowspan="2">$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>March</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see, the value always spans *down* the table, not up it; similarly, a `colspan` spans right, not left. In your second example in the question, there is no row below February for the value to span down to, so the attribute has no effect.

Comment: What if I need the $100 cell to be inside the third row? is there any trick i  can use? Cause in mobile I need the $100 cell go last after January and February

Comment: @AndreaScanu If the cell has a rowspan of 2 then by definition it is in *both* rows. You can align it vertically within that space, but I'm not sure that's what you're asking for. If you can define clearly what you want to achieve you could ask a new question - as discussed in the [tour], this site explicitly discourages continuing discussions beyond the scope of the original question.

Comment: Actually this is still relative to the main question how would I keep the view of the first example while keeping the html structure of the second one. I need the 100$ dollar cell to be inside the last tr not the first one, and that's because I gotta do something later with that cell (instead of occupying 2 rows on the right I want it to go under the 2 wors making it a 3 rows table (at a certain min with with display: table-cell;)